# What to do if the user drags a symbolic link or Alias into iTunes File Sharing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, file-sharing

My will use iTunes File Sharing so the user can drag files easily into the Documents directory of the app, using iTunes.

I never tried this but what if the user drags an alias or symbolic link in there? What happens? I guess that iTunes is clever and actually pulls in the real file, not the symbolic link. But assuming it's not clever, how will I deal with this in my app?

How can I detect this and tell the user that he dragged garbage to the documents dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSFileManager`' [`attributesOfItemAtPath:error`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW8) to get details on the file path. `NSFileType` key should tell you whether its a symlink or not.

Comment: Is it possible to drag symbolic links into iTunes?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to drag symlinks into iTunes. While the link is copied over, not the content it points to. Tested this myself.